# Linux create zip file with custom directories in it

Tags: linux, command-line, php, zip

I'm new here. My task is to create a zip file from php code. I need to password protect it and the server runs php 5.5 and password protection is not supported there so I need to execute a command from php to create a zip file. The folder structure I have the files in is: `sites/default/files/private/`. The structure of the zip file must be `<Document_Type>/document.extension`. I can get the document types from the code but how can I insert the files into a custom defined non-existing directory via `zip` command? I don't want to use the `-j` option because it will just put the files on the top level of the zip file.

Comment: Why aren't you creating the ZIP file from code? Aren't there some PHP libraries for creating ZIP archives? If you really need to use the external `zip` program, I suggest creating some temporary directories with the desired hierarchy and symlink from them to the actual files.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SuperUser. Your question is much more likely to get an answer if you include what you tried so far and describe how that does not solve the issue at hand.